# Converting Jquery to plain js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jsfiddle

I was working on some highchart stuff regarding removing some things from color axis, it all works great but as you know jsfiddle works on jquery, i managed to get it working with js

```
 load:function(nani){
          $(" .highcharts-coloraxis-grid > path, .highcharts-coloraxis-labels > text ").remove();
          },
          redraw:function(nani){
          $(" .highcharts-coloraxis-grid > path, .highcharts-coloraxis-labels > text ").remove();
          },
```

but when its time to move it to plain js I really have no idea how to do it.
Does anyone have solution how to translate this ?
Thanks
Here is the whole jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wf6x4ojh/4/

Comment: try setting `display: none` in your css

Comment: I cannot alter css because highcharts uses its own can it can ruin the structure of rendered object, it has to happen in function, first idea was to display:none because that works every time but this time it has to happen in js code. but thank you for suggestion Aswin

Comment: Hi @Milosh, You can disable the labels and the grid lines by options. Please check `gridLineWidth` and `labels` properties: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h40Lfvm1/

Comment: To be more precise to achieve complete behavior you need to add following in colorAxis object

colorAxis: {
labels: { enabled: false },
   tickLength: 0,
   gridLineWidth:0,
 },